# How can I set unlimited FPS in OpenTK?

Tags: c#, opentk

```
using (OpenTK.GameWindow game = new OpenTK.GameWindow())
{
    double fps = 60;
    game.Run(fps, fps);
}
```

With this I am able to set the fps to 60 or lower. But I want to have unlimited fps. How can I do this?

Comment: Not familiar with the Library/Framework, but what happens when you set it to zero?

Comment: Still capped at 60 fps. But I solved it: Vsync was enabled by default...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (OpenTK.GameWindow game = new OpenTK.GameWindow())
{
    double fps = 60;
    game.VSync = OpenTK.VSyncMode.Off;
    game.Run(fps, fps);
}
```

That solved it. So easy that I did not think of it:D

When you set fps now to 0 you get unlimited fps.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTK has 3 overloads for the method Run.

You can just use game.Run() without any parameters and will use unlimited fps.

Docs: https://opentk.net/api/OpenTK.GameWindow.html#OpenTK_GameWindow_Run

Cheers